# Netsuite SQL Expressions

Tags: sql, formula, netsuite, freetext

I need to use Netsute SQL expressions on a custom field.
There are certain criteria that the field needs to follow;

- If the cell contains only 1 (or none) capital letters, return the
  first 2 characters, capitalized.
- If the cell contains 2 (or more) capital letters, return only these.
- Also, If the cell contains a forward slash '/' then include the
  forward slash as well.

I will give some examples;

```
Light Blue
Dark Navy
Yellow
BlacK/ReD
blue check
WHite/NAvy/GreY
berry
```

should become

```
LB
DN
YE
BK/RD
BL
WH/NA/GY
BE
```

I know this might be easier to accomplish with suite script, but I don't have access to it, so I have to try and make it work with SQL and formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH({col}) <= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE({col}, '[A-Z]', '')) + 1
            THEN UPPER(SUBSTR({col}, 1, 2))
            ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE({col}, '[^A-Z/]', '')
       END AS output
FROM yourTable
```

The regex pattern `[^A-Z/]` should match everything which is *not* a capital letter or forward slash.  This then would be replaced with empty string, i.e. removed from the column.